# asp.net mvc Html.Textbox, unable to set value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox

in my route table I have this entry

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "myRoute",
            "route/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", start="", end="" }
        );
```

in my master page I have a line of code like so:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("foo", "bar") %>
```

If I access the page in the form of http://mysite.com/route/Home/Index/id/start/end the textbox renders OK with a value of "bar"
However if I access the page using the default parameters http://mysite.com/route/ the textbox does not have a value! In the emitted HTML it shows up like so:

```
<input id="foo" type="text" value="" name="foo"/>
```

it didn't set the value to "bar"...is this a bug? or is this not allowed in mvc master pages?

Comment: It looks fine to me, I copied and pasted your code exactly and i end up with a text box that has "bar" in it.  You might want to try restarting the app or VS?

Comment: Do you set any ViewData in the controller action before the view renders?

Comment: I have some stuff in my ViewData collection before the view renders, but I can't even get this simple case of using a simple string to work

Comment: more info..my route table has this entry:
routes.MapRoute(
                "myRoute",                                              // Route name
                "route/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}",     // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", start="", end="" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

If i am explicit about the url when I access the page (http://mysite.com/report/Home/Index/id/start/end) it will render the textbox ok.

If i rely on the default paramters (http://myiste/report/), the text box will not have a value

Answer (score 0):

it should work fine

"  <%= Html.TextBox("name", "Please enter your name...")%>

Output : < input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Please enter your name..." />

Answer (score 0):

```
   <%: Html.TextBox("foo", "bar") %>
```

sometimes you need to force it to be a simple html attribute as follows

```
   <%: Html.TextBox("foo", null,new{value="bar"}) %>
```